# Open url in parent webview with out creating a new webview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, webchromeclient, android-webview-javascript

I have an webpage which contain login button in it, On click of this login button it's opening new tab in Chrome.
I tried to load this webpage in my Webview, like in below code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView parentWebView, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        WebView chileWebView = new WebView(mContext);
        chileWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        chileWebView.setWebViewClient(...);
        parentWebView.addView(chileWebView, new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj).setWebView(chileWindowWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
```

But I need to load new url in same parentWebView. Is there any possibility to load this directly in to parentWebView like below without creating new childWebview?

```
((WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj).setWebView(parentWebView);
```

When I set `webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);`  it's loading `about:blank` page on click of login button.

Comment: Why are you creating a WebView inside your WebView here? 

`@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

       WebView newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    ...
    }`

You should create a single WebView inside your Fragment/Activity. Creating multiple WebViews will open a Pandora's box of a whole lot of potential issues.

Comment: To load url in same webview, we can't use this code. Above code will open url in new webview inside a dialog. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58386309